# Pulp Solver Error, unable to use .solve()

Tags: python, pulp

I'm having difficulty with .solve() for my PuLP problem. I'm receiving the error:

PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more detailscbc

I'm not sure how to correct it. Any advice is appreciated.

```
import pulp
import pandas as pd

solver_list = pulp.listSolvers()

#read in excel file
df = pd.read_excel (r'/Users/***/Desktop/diet.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print (df)

#nested list from values
diet_data = df.values.tolist()

#list of foods
foods = [x[0] for x in diet_data]
#meats = 


# Make dictionaries (key / value pairs) from the lists
# Key = food name
# Value = value
price = {x[0]:x[1] for x in diet_data}
cals = {x[0]:x[3] for x in diet_data}
cholesterol = {x[0]:x[4] for x in diet_data}
fat = {x[0]:x[5] for x in diet_data}
sodium = {x[0]:x[6] for x in diet_data}
carbs = {x[0]:x[7] for x in diet_data}
fiber = {x[0]:x[8] for x in diet_data}
protein = {x[0]:x[9] for x in diet_data}
vitA = {x[0]:x[10] for x in diet_data}
vitC = {x[0]:x[11] for x in diet_data}
calcium= {x[0]:x[12] for x in diet_data}
iron = {x[0]:x[13] for x in diet_data}

#creating optimization problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("DietProblem", pulp.LpMinimize)


# Creating the variables
lp_variables = pulp.LpVariable.dicts( "Amounts", foods, 0 )

# Creating objective function
# objective function
prob += pulp.lpSum(price[i] * lp_variables[i] for i in foods)
# min 1500 cals         
prob += pulp.lpSum(cals[i] * lp_variables[i] for i in foods) >= 1500 
# max 2500 cals 
prob += pulp.lpSum(cals[i] * lp_variables[i] for i in foods) <= 2500 
# min 30g chol 
prob += pulp.lpSum(cholesterol[i] * lp_variables[i] for i in foods) >= 30 
# max 240g chol 
prob += pulp.lpSum(cholesterol[i] * lp_variables[i] for i in foods) <= 240  


solution = prob.solve()
```

Comment: Your formulation appears correct.  Without data, it is tough to troubleshoot.  Try printing out one or two of your data dictionaries to see if it is what you expect.  Also, check your data frame for non-numeric values.  `df.info()`.  If you are still stuck, copy/paste a portion of your excel file into your post to help T/S.  You can probably save it as a .csv (which is better anyway) and post a handful of rows, formatted as code.

Comment: I do believe there are some NaNs. I'll try cleaning it up! Thank You!